# my code compiles and execute perfectly but there is a part of that is like not read during execution

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, printf

I'm some kind of beginner in programming, I know some Javascript, C# and now learning C.
I created a simple mini-game in C called more or less(the computer chooses a random number, and you have to guess that number with minimum shots possible) so the code compiles and works perfectly except to show the congratulation part and the for loop to print the score. it is like they're not read at all.
I tried to put the for loop inside the while loop. but it just scrapped the code.
I also removed the `int argc, char *argv[]` but it did nothing.
I tried to find help but nothing

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int MAX = 100, MIN = 1;   
    int enteredNumber;
    int nombreMystere;
    int NombreDeCoups;
    //ask user for input (integer)
    printf("quel est le nombre? \n");
    scanf("%d", &enteredNumber);
    
    //generation of random number
    srand(time(NULL));//srand() must be used just once in any program
    nombreMystere = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;//rand() is a function to provide random number

//program loop. repeats until user finds number
while (enteredNumber != nombreMystere)
    {
        if (enteredNumber < nombreMystere)//if loop, that shows if it,s more or less to provide
        {
            printf("c'est plus! \n");
        }
        else if (enteredNumber > nombreMystere)
        {
            printf("c'est moins! \n");
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Bravo! Vous avez trouve le bon nombre");
        }
        
        printf("quel est le nombre? \n"); //reprompts user until find the number
        scanf("%d", &enteredNumber);
        
    }
    for (NombreDeCoups = 0; enteredNumber =! nombreMystere; NombreDeCoups++) // loop to give score of how many tries user did
        {
            printf("en %d coups", &NombreDeCoups);
        }
    
}```
````

Comment: I don't understand why your score needs to be printed in a loop, but I assume the `=!` is supposed to be a `!=` and you know `enteredNumber != nombreMystere` can't be true at the start of your `for` loop or you wouldn't have exited the `while` loop previous (it's the same condition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile with warnings:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   41 |             printf("en %d coups", &NombreDeCoups);
      |                        ~^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and switch to

```
printf("en %d coups", NombreDeCoups);
```

This is also suspicious:

```
demo.c:39:29: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
   39 |     for (NombreDeCoups = 0; enteredNumber =! nombreMystere; NombreDeCoups++)
```

You mean `enteredNumber != nombreMystere`, but you don't need another loop to get score of how many tries user did, just increment the counter at the end of each iteration and print the result outside the loop:

```
int NombreDeCoups = 0;

while (enteredNumber != nombreMystere)
{
    ...
    NombreDeCoups++;
}
printf("en %d coups", NombreDeCoups);
```

Comment: thank you. when I put NombreDeCoups++ Inside the while loop and print outside. it works now

Answer (score 0):

For starters this else statement

```
    else 
    {
        printf("Bravo! Vous avez trouve le bon nombre");
    }
```

never gets the control within the while loop

```
while (enteredNumber != nombreMystere)
```

because the body of the loop is executed only when `enteredNumber` is not equal to  `nombreMystere`.

You need to move the sub-statement of the else statement outside the while loop.

In this for loop the purpose of which is unclear

```
    for (NombreDeCoups = 0; enteredNumber =! nombreMystere; NombreDeCoups++) // loop to give score of how many tries user did

    {
        printf("en %d coups", &NombreDeCoups);
    }
```

you are using incorrect argument expression `&NombreDeCoups` instead of `NombreDeCoups` in the call of `printf`.